# Windows phone Navigation issue

Tags: windows-phone

I have an application where from the MainPage.xaml I navigate to a page called say two.xaml.

In Two.xaml I then navigate to Three.xaml..

Now for Three.xaml I want to navigate back to the mainPage.Xaml.

In Three.xaml if I do

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

I get an InvalidOperationException.

If I do

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

the system will crate another instance of MainPage.xaml, which I do not want as it will lose its original state.

Anyone have solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can save the actual state for example in the State-Property of the [PhoneApplicationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff707299%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) Class, then Navigate through your pages and when getting back to the MainPage you just implement the OnNavigatedTo()-method of the MainPage and load the State-Data.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This would be a best practice anyway, I believe

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you are not supposed to manipulating the back stack in your app.
What cordellcp3 says may be a good idea to implement

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to navigate in this way:
MainPage->PageTwo->PageThree
User presses Back Button and goes to MainPage you can use this:
NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()
[documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx)

hope it helps